# SQL Server database on Client machine

Tags: c#, sql, database, sql-server-2008-r2, client

My application contains a SQL Server 2008 R2 database.

If I want to install the application on some client's machine, do I need to install the SQL Server 2008 R2 database as well?

Or is there any shortcut to access to database without installation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not have to install sql server on every machine that you want to run your client on, but it has to be installed in at least one place, and each client has to be able to access one sql server, possibly via the internet.

Comment: But this client is a single one, as stand alone, so it has to be installed?

Comment: @MitjaBonca: yes, if it's a single PC solution and your application uses SQL Server, then you **must** install SQL Server on that PC as well